# the double curly braces in the Laravel do not work

Tags: php, laravel

I recently started learning Laravel. I have a problem with double brackets.
I write this code in web.php file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('test', function () {
    $name = request('name');
    return view('test',[
        'name' => $name
    ]);
});
```

And then this code in test.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name = "viewport"
    content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0 "
    charset="UTF-8">
    <meta
    http-equiv = "X-UA-Compatible"
    content = "ie=edge"
    >
    
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body> <h1>{{$name}}</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

In browser it shows "{{$name}}"
I cannot find solution so plis help me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The double curly braces syntax requires `Blade engine`.

So, you need to rename your `test.php` to `test.blade.php`

Comment: Thank you!It works now. I am new at Laravel, and thats why I make this stupid mistakes..

Comment: Glad to help ^-^